# Python Threading, Arg turns itself into list

Tags: python, multithreading, list, args

OK, so I have a function, Main Thread

```
def main_thread(self, item):
     print(item)
```

And it's called with

```
item = self.queue.pop(0)
print(item)
threading.Thread(target=self.main_thread,args=(item)).start()
```

The queue item is 'something' when I print it before calling the thread, it prints right. but for some reason its always turned into a list `s,o,m,e,t,h,i,n,g,` meaning, I cant use

```
def main_thread(self, item):
```

because it says im trying to pass in 10 args, each letter being 1. 
if i use

```
def main_thread(self, *args):
```

i just get 10 args. i never had this problem before, but surely there must be a better way than re-building the string letter by letter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

args should be a tuple, you are passing a string so each character is being interpreted as a single argument:

```
args=(item,) # <- add a , to make a tuple
```

Strings are iterable so it is equivalent to the difference between:

```
In [2]: for ele in s:
   ...:     print(s)
   ...:     
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar

In [3]: for ele in (s,):
           print(s)
   ...:     
foobar
```

Comment: No worries, it is an easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 2):

that's because you are not passing a tuple to the function. try this one:

```
threading.Thread(target=self.main_thread,args=(item,)).start()
```

Comment: ahhhh yes, just like in sqlite. thanks, cant believe i missed that! thanks a million